# Can the Microsoft TextTransform utility be used standalone?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, t4, css

I need to use the TextTransform tool in a standalone mode. But it doesn't want to run on machines that don't have Visual Studio installed. Has someone figured out how to do this?

Comment: AFAIK, this is not possible. TextTransform has dependency on Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating assembly - I believe that this assembly is part of Visual Studio SDK and prerequisite for SDK is Visual Studio.

Comment: Agreed with VinayC.  You can go with something else, though, such as NVelocity.  There are options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using this solely on a build machine, then as of Visual Studio 2010, you are licensed to copy the dlls for text templating from the GAC of a Visual Studio installed machine to the build server.

We accidentally omitted the filenames from the buildserver.txt file in Visual Studio 2010 RTM, but we've corrected that for Visual Studio 2010 SP1.

T4 isn't licensed for use on machines other than build servers that do not have Visual Studio installed.

Comment: I had seen another post along these lines as well, and tried copying TextTransform.exe and Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating.dll over, but it didn't work. It complained "Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information." Do you know exactly what I need to copy?

Comment: What version are you using? If it is 2010 then you'll need the TextTemplating.Interfaces.dll as well.

Comment: Ya. We are on 2010. And I am using the .NET 3.5 version of the utility. I'll try that. Thanks! I actually resorted to using the utility out of the Mono distribution. But it has a lot of quirks. I'd rather use the real thing.

Comment: This answer helped with the DLL locations: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1906466/546004