# Template can now be generated without visual studio dependencies?

Tags: c#, asp.net, wpf, visual-studio, t4

There was a former question here:
[Can the Microsoft TextTransform utility be used standalone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4505741/can-the-microsoft-texttransform-utility-be-used-standalone)

Since VS2010 is it still true as I can read:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/garethj/archive/2010/04/15/what-s-new-in-t4-in-visual-studio-2010.aspx

> Preprocessed templates to allow embedding of template-based generation in arbitrary applications without a runtime T4 dependency. There is a new custom tool, new service APIs and new engine APIs to support this feature.

I'm not asking about T4 tutorial, my question is more about deployment : is the answer to the old question still true or did it change ?

Answer (score 1):

Preprocessed templates in Visual Studio 2010 and above allow you to create templates in Visual Studio that can be packaged up in an assembly and incorporated into any application with no dependencies on Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

I think [Google](http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=t4+preprocessed+templates) can help here. See [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43394/T4-Preprocessed-Text-Templates-in-Visual-Studio-20.aspx) or [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee844259.aspx) for instance.

Comment: I'm not asking about T4 tutorial, my question is more about deployment : is the answer to the old question still true or did it change ?