# t4mvc doesn't work with VS2010 .Net 3.5

Tags: visual-studio-2010, t4mvc

I converted my solution to run with VS2010 from VS2008. But I'm still running .Net 3.5 instead of 4. T4MVC has stopped working and is not able to generate any code. Would be great if you could please help with this.

I've tried to look for this issue, but can't find a solution. I found one where the conversion was to VS2010 .Net4.0, but that didn't help me.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried the following, if this helps anyone:

1. I followed the steps listed here first [Cannot get T4MVC to work with VS2010 and ASP.NET MVC 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1906341/cannot-get-t4mvc-to-work-with-vs2010-and-asp-net-mvc-2)
2. As my solution is still running .net 3.5, it complained when I referenced the the TextTemplating DLLs, but I still tried to build the solution for T4MVC to run.
3. Then I tried changing the language in t4mvc.tt file from <#@ template language="C#v3.5" debug="true" hostspecific="true" #> to <#@ template language="C#" debug="true" hostspecific="true" #> and built the solution
4. Finally I went back to version 2.6.15, changed the language back to C#v3.5, removed the text templating references and built the solution again.

Don't really know what fixed the issue but its fixed for now. The only manual change that I had to do was in the T4MVC.cs file where instead of a closing bracket, the T4MVC generator put double quotes.

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you right click on the .tt file a choose 'Run Custom Tool'?  Under properties for t4mvc.tt, you should see Custom Tool set to 'TextTemplatingFileGenerator'.

Comment: I tweaked it a bit yesterday. I tried a few things, not sure what fixed it. I was using the 2.4 version before but went back to version 2.15 and it seems to be working fine now.